# <p:autoComplete> inside cell editable <p:dataTable> not invoking complete method

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a dataTable which has cell editing and global filter capability:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl01" value="#{userMappingBacking.staffList}" editable="true" editMode="cell" filteredValue="#{userMappingBacking.staffListFiltered}" var="s" rowKey="#{s.id}" widgetVar="tbl101WV">
  ...               
  <f:facet name="header">
     <p:outputPanel>
       <p:toolbar>
         <p:toolbarGroup align="${text.line_start}">
           <p:commandButton value="#{text.save}" action="#{userMappingBacking.saveChanges}" update="msgs"/>
         </p:toolbarGroup>
         <p:toolbarGroup align="${text.line_end}">
           <h:outputText value="#{text.search_all_fields}:"/>
           <p:spacer width="10"/>
           <h:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('tbl101WV').filter()" />
         </p:toolbarGroup>
       </p:toolbar>
     </p:outputPanel>
  </f:facet>
  ...
  <p:column headerText="#{text.user}" filterBy="#{s.userName}" filterable="false">
    <p:cellEditor id="ceUser">
      <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{s.userName}"/></f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
        <p:autoComplete id="acUser" dropdown="true" value="#{s.userName}" completeMethod="#{userMappingBacking.completeUnAssignedUser}"/>
      </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and the backing bean `userMappingBacking` supports all the methods and works fine.

My problem is quite strange, the `<p:autoComplete id="acUser"...` doesn't invoke the complete method unless a filter is applied to the table, after a filter application every thing works fine, but before that no values are completed in the p:autoComplete.

Could any one help or give an insight into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem to be in the backing bean, I had 3 lists:

```
staffList = new ArrayList<>();
staffListFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
userDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
```

that I fill in a viewAction listener

```
public void loadStaffListAction() {
    staffList = zaties.listAllStaff();
    staffListFiltered = zaties.listAllStaff();
    userDTOList = iacw.listAllUsers();
}
```

the problem was having 2 different lists `staffList` and `staffListFiltered` filled with different objects from the service, so changing the code like this:

```
public void loadStaffListAction() {
    staffList = zaties.listAllStaff();
    staffListFiltered = staffList;
    userDTOList = iacw.listAllUsers();
}
```

and this solved the problem, nevertheless this is not the best practice, as explained below.

**Common Error:**

in the primefaces showcase for [filtered datatable](http://localhost:5282/showcase-6.1/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) the never initialize the `filteredValue` list to any thing, they leave it as `null` so the datatable filter logic initialize it in the right way, paying attention to this detail I advise:

---

*Don't initialize any thing unless you get an error.*

---

comments are welcome!

Comment: @BalusC I would appreciate any comment or insight from you.